# Do you need to check both ends of a network cable test tool or are they the always the same?

Tags: networking, cable-tester

When using a Catx network tester like the image below, do you need to view both ends of the cable / tester to confirm the cable / termination is good ?

Do both ends of the network test tool always show the same information ? Or could there be circumstances where one end would show the correct information, but the other end would show different information ?

[image: image of Catx network tester tool]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In later times to connect computer to computer without any switches or hubs there was used `Cross over cable`. To connect computer to switch, hub or router there may be used `Straight-through cable` instead. **They are not the same!** See pictures:

[image: Cross over cable]

---

[image: Straight-through cable]

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends on the model of the tester, but usually the master side of the tester just cycles through all lines in order and puts a signal on them, while the remote side displays which line is currently active.

So with regard to "is this line properly connected", there is no difference. However, if the remote side doesn't cycle through all lines in order, then either you have a crossover cable as described in the other answer, or, if you crimped the cable yourself, you made a mistake while crimping (happened to me a few times). This is unlikely to happen with a cable you bought, but better safe then sorry.

So yes, you need to check both sides.